# Parse a real number set from latex to sympy

Tags: python, latex, sympy

Consider a set given in latex, say

`$[0;\sqrt{3}) \cup \{2;3\} \cup (4;+\infty)$`

Is there a fast way to parse this string into a sympy set?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256644/convert-latex-to-sympy-format).

Comment: Oh thank you! Unfortunately, it looks like those things are about parsing expressions, not sets.
Btw, sympy has a good parser for latex expressions as well

Comment: @M-Chen-3 the grammar from `latex2sympy` library mentioned [in the answer you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288212) to is actually ported to [`LaTeX.g4`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/parsing/latex/LaTeX.g4) , and made available through `sympy.parsing.latex.parse_latex` inside sympy